# Update Table with two foreach

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, foreach

I have two tables:

table IMAGES

```
id_images | dir_image | post_id
     1      image1.jpg   1
     2      image2.jpg   1
     3      image3.jpg   1
     4      image4.jpg   1
     5      image5.jpg   2
     6      image6.jpg   2
     7      image7.jpg   2
     8      image8.jpg   2
```

table POSTS

```
id_post   |          slug        |   title
 1           title_post            Title Post 
 2           title_post_2          Title Post 2
```

PHP

```
     public function update($idsimages, $dir_images, $idPost, $title, $slug)
                {
                    try {
                    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE posts SET
    title = :title, 
    slug = :slug,
    WHERE id_post=:id_post");

                    $stmt->bindParam(":id_post",$idPost);
                    $stmt->bindParam(":title",$title);  
                    $stmt->bindParam(":slug",$slug); 
                    $stmt->execute();


                    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE images SET
    dir_images = :dir_images
WHERE id_images = :id_images");


                    foreach ($idsimages as $idsimage) { 


                            foreach ($dir_images as $item){

                                $stmt->bindParam(":id_images", $idsimage);
                                $stmt->bindParam(":dir_images", $item);             

                             }  //end foreach dir_images                

                       $stmt->execute();

                    } // end foreach idsimages


                    return true;
                }
                catch(PDOException $e) {
                    echo $e->getMessage();    
                    return false;
                }
                }
```

The variable `$idsimages` is an array of ids the `$id_images`column

The variable `$dir_images` is an array of urls that should be updated according to the id of the array `$idsimages`

With php code above correctly updates the title of the post table, but is not updating the table images

---

**PRINTS**

**print_r ($idsimages);**

```
Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 6 [2] => 7 [3] => 8 )
```

**print_r ($dir_images);**

```
Array ( [0] => uploads/images/image5.jpg [1] => uploads/images/image6.jpg [2] => uploads/images/image7.jpg [3] => uploads/images/image8.jpg)
```

if I insert echo in function:

```
$stmt->bindParam(":id_images", $idsimage);
echo $idsimage;
$stmt->bindParam(":dir_images", $item); 
echo $item;
```

return:

```
5 image5.PNG 5 image6.jpg 5 image6.jpg 5  image6.jpg
6 image5.PNG 6 image6.jpg 6 image6.jpg 6 image6.jpg
7 image5.PNG 7 image6.jpg 7 image6.jpg 7 image6.jpg
8 image5.PNG 8 image6.jpg 8 image6.jpg 8 image6.jpg
```

Comment: The bindParam's in your inner loop will be overwritten on each iteration.

Comment: When you bind param :dir_image, shouldn't it be :dir_images ?

Comment: @dnFer Thank´s it was just a typo in my question I corrected

Comment: @noahnu Thanks I printed the variables `$idsimage` and `$item` they are being repeated several times

Comment: Do `$idsimages` and `$idsimage` has equals length? And you want to set `dir_images` for records with specified `id_images`?

Comment: @mnv yes,  it would be better to use the `do while`?

Comment: Than remove nested foreach, as below in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE images SET
   dir_images = :dir_images
   WHERE id_images = :id_images");

foreach ($idsimages as $key => $idsimage) { 
    $stmt->bindParam(":id_images", $idsimage);
    $stmt->bindParam(":dir_images", $dir_images[$key]);             

    $stmt->execute();
} // end foreach idsimages
```

Comment: but `$idsimage` It's also an array

Comment: How looks `$idsimage` and `$dir_images`?

Comment: Show also scructure of `images` table. Maybe you have typo in column names `dir_images` -> `dir_image` and `id_images` -> `id_image`